# Android how to find out which dialog generated event

Tags: java, android

In my activity I'm using a lot of dialogs (instances of `AlertDialog.Builder` class) and I want to add listeners (instances of `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface) to some buttons or items of these dialogs

but I want my activity to be listener of all these buttons and items so I implemented `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` in my activity.

So when user presses for example button of some dialog, method `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` will be called.

And my question is how can I in implementation of this method find out which dialog generated event?

Because I can only find out which button user pressed or which item user clicked using `which` parameter but `dialog` parameter provides only `cancel()` and `dismiss()` methods.

Comment: Set some flag for each button and pass it to your dialog method and code according to those flag.

Comment: But I'm adding buttons like this: new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setPositiveButton("Label", this)... so I'm setting only labels and listeners.